# Redux : Getting null value after calling Reducer in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm making an API Call to get a value that i will store in my `reducer`. Although when i'm calling my reducer i'm getting `null`.

here is my code to get the value :

```
export function getValue(token) {
  return fetch('URI', { method: 'GET'})
  .then(response => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      return response.value;
    });
}
```

Then i have my redux :

```
    const UPDATE_VALUE = 'user/UPDATE_VALUE';
    ...
        const initialState = {
      myValue: null,
    };
    export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
     case UPDATE_VALUE:
      return {
        ...state,
        myValue: action.value
      };
     default:
      return state;
  }
}
    export function updateValue(value) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_VALUE,
    value,
  };
}
```

And here i call the api to stock the value. I'm getting the value and it existes but when i want to store and get it's value i'm getting null :

```
const getMyValue = new Promise((resolve) => {
    return getMyValue(token).then((value) => {
      updateValue(value === null ? null : value);
      resolve();
    });
  });
```

Comment: You are using the ```case``` without the switch expression. Was that a typo?

Comment: Yes .. just didn't copy the whole code.